# How can I properly get total amounts in my MPAndroid LineChart with Firebase data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, linechart

I am building a MPAndroid LineChart in Android Studio using Java and I need some assistance, I need the following;

1. Format my x values so I can get to see values as "MMM, dd"
2. I get to show amounts daily but if there is more than 1 item on a day I need to totalize, example, if on april 2 I have 2 items 20,000 and 10,000 I want my chart to show April, 2 30,000.

this is my LineChart;

[image]

this is the code where I am trying to do the total based on the day but it is not working.

```
private void retrieveChartData() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    String year = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            days.clear();

            ArrayList<Entry> data = new ArrayList<>();

            if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Expense expense = dataSnapshot.getValue(Expense.class);

                    assert expense != null;
                    if (expense.getDate().substring(6, 10).equals(year)) {
                        boolean exists = false;
                        int count = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++) {
                            count = i;
                            exists = days.get(i).getDate().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase(expense.getDate().substring(0, 2));
                            if (exists) break;
                        }
                        if (exists) {
                            days.get(count).setAmount(days.get(count).getAmount() + expense.getAmount());
                        } else {
                            days.add(expense);
                        }
                    }

                    data.add(new Entry(Integer.parseInt(expense.getDate().substring(0, 2)), expense.getAmount()));
                }
                showChart(data);

            } else {
                lineChart.clear();
                lineChart.invalidate();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

this is my realtime data base in firebase.

[image]

Comment: "it is not working" is really hard to help with. When you set breakpoints on all important lines in this code and then run in the debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? --- Also: never ignore errors. At its least `onCancelled` should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the expected result.

I post the snipet for future inquiries.

```
private void retrieveChartData() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    String year = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            days.clear();

            ArrayList<Entry> data = new ArrayList<>();
            int count = 0;
            if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Expense expense = dataSnapshot.getValue(Expense.class);

                    assert expense != null;
                    if (expense.getDate().substring(6, 10).equals(year)) {
                        boolean exists = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++) {
                            count = i;
                            exists = days.get(i).getDate().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase(expense.getDate().substring(0, 2));
                            if (exists) break;
                        }
                        if (exists) {
                            days.get(count).setAmount(days.get(count).getAmount() + expense.getAmount());
                        } else {
                            days.add(expense);
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++) {
                    data.add(new Entry(Integer.parseInt(days.get(i).getDate().substring(0, 2)), days.get(i).getAmount()));
                }
                showChart(data);

            } else {
                lineChart.clear();
                lineChart.invalidate();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            throw error.toException();
        }
    });
}
```